# Is it feasible to have a cluster of two MongoDB On Premise VMs and a DocumentDB on AWS?

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb, disaster-recovery

We are considering conducting proof-of-concept tests in which we will have two On-Premise MongoDB machines and a third one using DocumentDB on AWS.

We are examining all the functionality differences and talking to vendors, but no one can answer the question: Is it viable to have two On-Premise MongoDB machines and a DocumentDB on AWS? We only see people discussing migrating data from On-Premise MongoDB to DocumentDB in the cloud, but not running all three simultaneously. In other words, we want to know if, for example, our On-Premise MongoDB VMs fail, whether DocumentDB will be able to handle production.

I assume it is almost unfeasible, but right now, we are asked to conduct this test before migrating the entire cluster to DocumentDB.

All of this would require us to review all the functionalities in our application to see if they are compatible between both technologies. We would like to know if anyone in this forum has tried this before we venture into a dead-end.

Thank you all for your responses.

Best regards

So far, we have conducted very basic tests, such as creating a DocumentDB cluster and connecting it to our MongoDB to transfer data, albeit in small quantities. The only thing we have noticed is that, when the disaster recovery (DR) begins, if we create new collections in our MongoDB database, they are not reflected in DocumentDB unless we initiate a new migration. In other words, the data is being updated, but the new collections created in MongoDB are not automatically generated in DocumentDB. It is possible that we have not configured the cloud overflow properly.

Comment: Have a look at [Supported MongoDB APIs, Operations, and Data Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html) and [Functional Differences: Amazon DocumentDB and MongoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html). If all functions you need are supported, then I think you can do it.

Comment: If you mean having all 3 machines in the same replica set, it might work if you are lucky.  I don't think AWS and MongoDB collaborate on the replication protocol.  This is speculation: If anything at all goes wrong, I doubt either company would help you.